# Pandas GroupBy Mean of Large DataSet in CSV

Tags: python, pandas

A common SQLism is "Select A, mean(X) from table group by A" and I would like to replicate this in pandas. Suppose that the data is stored in something like a CSV file and is too big to be loaded into memory.

If the CSV could fit in memory a simple two-liner would suffice:

```
data=pandas.read_csv("report.csv")
mean=data.groupby(data.A).mean()
```

When the CSV cannot be read into memory one might try:

```
chunks=pandas.read_csv("report.csv",chunksize=whatever)
cmeans=pandas.concat([chunk.groupby(data.A).mean() for chunk in chunks])
badMeans=cmeans.groupby(cmeans.A).mean()
```

Except that the resulting cmeans table contains repeated entries for each distinct value of A, one for each appearance of that value of A in distinct chunks (since read_csv's chunksize knows nothing about the grouping fields). As a result the final badMeans table has the wrong answer... it needs to compute a weighted average mean.

So a working approach seems to be something like:

```
final=pandas.DataFrame({"A":[],"mean":[],"cnt":[]})
for chunk in chunks:
    t=chunk.groupby(chunk.A).sum()
    c=chunk.groupby(chunk.A).count()
    cmean=pandas.DataFrame({"tot":t,"cnt":c}).reset_index()
    joined=pandas.concat(final,cmean)
    final=joined.groupby(joined.A).sum().reset_indeX()

mean=final.tot/final.cnt
```

Am I missing something? This seems insanely complicated... I would rather write a for loop that processes a CSV line by line than deal with this. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 10):

I think you could do something like the following which seems a bit simpler to me. I made the following data:

```
id,val
A,2
A,5
B,4
A,2
C,9
A,7
B,6
B,1
B,2
C,4
C,4
A,6
A,9
A,10
A,11
C,12
A,4
A,4
B,6
B,5
C,7
C,8
B,9
B,10
B,11
A,20
```

I'll do chunks of 5:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv("foo.csv",chunksize=5)
pieces = [x.groupby('id')['val'].agg(['sum','count']) for x in chunks]

agg = pd.concat(pieces).groupby(level=0).sum()
print agg['sum']/agg['count']

id
A     7.272727
B     6.000000
C     7.333333
```

Compared to the non-chunk version:

```
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
print df.groupby('id')['val'].mean()

id
A     7.272727
B     6.000000
C     7.333333
```

Comment: Thanks that is certainly better... although not at all obvious (and there are some concerns about overflowing the ints). Hopefully some future version of Pandas will make this easier.

Comment: see this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3202; this is a bit non-trivial to do correctly; just takes a motivated contributor!