# Large data using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a very big CSV file (tens of Gigas) containing web logs with the following columns: `user_id, time_stamp, category_clicked`. I have to build a scorer to identify what categories users like and dislike.

My problem comes when I have to load my CSV using `pandas.read_csv` . Indeed, I would like to use the `chunksize` parameter to split it, but since I have to proceed a '`groupby` operation' on the `user_id`s to make my calculation (I don't want my score to be too trivial), I don't know how to smartly split my data because If I only use chunsize, I won't be able to properly use groupby.

To be simple, I want to do a calculation for each user, which depends on the timestamp and the category clicked. For instance, give 1 point to the user if his click happened one month ago, 2 points if it happened two weeks ago, and 4 points if it happened last week.

How can I do? And I am missing something?

Comment: Possibly related: [Pandas GroupBy Mean of Large DataSet in CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23190156/478288).

Comment: I am sorry but It is not really related, because the solution given is very specific to the function mean(), and won't work in my case.

Comment: You basically need to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798209/pandas-group-by-query-on-large-data-in-hdfstore. In a nutshell, read in your data using read_csv, save to a hdfstore (table format). Then  you can get the keys of the groupby (user_id), and aggregate as needed with a minimum of queries. This is quite scalable.

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone could give me more details in the case that there is more than a million groups. I think It could be usefull to more than me.