# Get the mean value while using chunksize

Tags: python, pandas

I have this piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190156/pandas-groupby-mean-of-large-dataset-in-csv) that helps me getting the mean value while using chunksize on python.

```
chunks = pd.read_csv("f.csv",chunksize=3)
pieces = [x.groupby('id')['val'].agg(['sum','count']) for x in chunks]

agg = pd.concat(pieces).groupby(level=0).sum()
print agg['sum']/agg['count']
```

**Result**
id
A     7.272727
B     6.000000
C     7.333333

But for my new scenario I don`t need to group by ID, but get the overall mean value (modifying a bit the structure, do not using an one line for loop, but an "indented-for loop")

I have tried this, but it`s not working.

```
path = r"f.CSV"
for df in pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=3):
    pieces = [df.groupby(level=0).agg(['sum','count'])]
agg = pd.concat(pieces).groupby(level=0).sum()
print (agg['sum']/agg['count'])
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in your code?  You are not defining `pieces` outside the loop so at the end, it will contain only last chunk's data.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you really need to work with chunks instead of the entire csv at once?

Comment: @Ank **KeyError: 'sum'**.
I have declared pieces, num and lista.

Comment: @not_speshal I am expecting something like 6.8686866. Just the mean value over the 'val' column. I really need to do chunksize, since my csv has over 100gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store running totals and counts in variables instead of using dataframes if all you need to work with in the end is the average:

```
import pandas as pd
sum_vals, counter = 0, 0
for df in pd.read_csv("foo.csv", chunksize=3):
    sum_vals += df["val"].sum()
    counter += df["val"].count()
print (sum_vals/counter)
```