# Python pandas read large csv with chunk

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to optimize my code when reading large CSV files.

I saw on severals sites that we can use "chunksize" with pandas.

I use the code to read csv file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(zf.open(f) , skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5], header=None, low_memory=False)
for _, df in data.groupby(data[0].eq("No.").cumsum()):
     dfs = []
     df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1:].values, columns=df.iloc[0].fillna(99))
     dfs.append(df.rename_axis(columns=None))
     date_pattern='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'
     df['epoch'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(time.mktime(time.strptime(row.time,date_pattern))), axis=1) # create epoch as a column
     for each_column in list(df.columns)[2:-1]:
     others line with "each_column" ...
     ...
```

I trying with the code bellow with chunksize, but i get an error.

```
data = pd.read_csv(zf.open(f) , skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5], header=None, low_memory=False, chunksize=1000)
    for _, df in data.groupby(data[0].eq("No.").cumsum()):
         dfs = []
         df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1:].values, columns=df.iloc[0].fillna(99))
         dfs.append(df.rename_axis(columns=None))
         date_pattern='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'
         df['epoch'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(time.mktime(time.strptime(row.time,date_pattern))), axis=1) # create epoch as a column
         for each_column in list(df.columns)[2:-1]:
         others line with "each_column"
```

Error:

```
on 0: Process Process-22:9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
          self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
          self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/import2grafana/libs/parsecsv.py", line 236, in readcsv_multi_thread
          for _, df in data.groupby(data[0].eq("No.").cumsum()):
AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Is it possible to use chuncksize with groupby ?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Grouping items requires having all of the data, since the first item might need to be grouped with the last.  So this could never work.  The documentation indicates that `chunksize` causes the `pandas.read_csv` command to return a `TextFileReader` object, expecting that you are going to be using the data one row at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas GroupBy Mean of Large DataSet in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190156/pandas-groupby-mean-of-large-dataset-in-csv)

Answer (score 1):

Chunksize will TextFileReader,

```
for _, df in data:
```

the method of DataFrame should apply on df, for example.

```
data = pd.read_csv(zf.open(f) , skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5], header=None, low_memory=False)
for _, df in data:
    df = df.groupby(data[0].eq("No.").cumsum())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `groupby` on `data`. Try something like:

```
dfs = []
for df in data:
   for _, subdf in chunk.groupby(data[0].eq("No.").cumsum()):
       # do stuff here
       dfs.append(subdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found correct way:

```
  chunk_size = 100000000000  # Set your desired chunk size here
  data_reader = pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], header=None, low_memory=False, chunksize=chunk_size)
  for data_chunk in data_reader:
      for _, df in data_chunk.groupby(data_chunk[0].eq("No.").cumsum()):
          dfs = []
          df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1:].values, columns=df.iloc[0].fillna(99))
          dfs.append(df.rename_axis(columns=None))
          date_pattern = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'
          df['epoch'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(time.mktime(time.strptime(row.time, date_pattern))), axis=1)
          for each_column in list(df.columns)[2:-1]:
             some stuff lines
```

thank for your help.

Comment: The time hasn't change, no beneficts with this way. I don't understand who i can optimize